# Shared element transition from RecyclerView to activity not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I want to use shared element transition from `RecyclerView` item to another `Activity`, but it's not working. The `RecyclerView` is inside a `fragment`, and this is `onClick` listener of `RecyclerView` item

```
  @Override 
    public void onProductItemClick(int pos, PromoORProduct promoORProduct, ImageView shareImageView) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductPreviewAct_.class);
    intent.putExtra("OBJECT", promoORProduct);
    intent.putExtra(ProductPreviewAct.SMALL_IMAGE_TRANSITION_NAME, "small_img" + pos);
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), shareImageView, "small_img" + pos);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
```

listener is called from onBindViewHolder of my adapter

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ProductsViewHolder) {
            final PromoORProduct user = items.get(position);
            ProductsViewHolder userViewHolder = (ProductsViewHolder) holder;
                ViewCompat.setTransitionName(userViewHolder.imgSmall, "small_img"+position);
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    productsItemClickListener.onProductItemClick(holder.getAdapterPosition(), user, ((ProductsViewHolder) holder).imgSmall);
                }
            });
            userViewHolder.bind(user, this);
        } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
            LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
            loadingViewHolder.progressBar1.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }
```

in my called activity's onCreate

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_preview);
        imgSmall = findViewById(R.id.imgSmall2);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_transaction));
            String imageTransitionName = extras.getString(SMALL_IMAGE_TRANSITION_NAME);
            imgSmall.setTransitionName(imageTransitionName);
        }

    }
```

the output is weird, the image is fading out in the fragment and popping in the called activity's imageview and when exit the same. Any ideas...
Thanx a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After days of struggle found it, in case anyone else has similar problem...

Check your manifes's application
I had set  `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` 
Removed it and it all works like a charm

Comment: any idea on why this happened? It sounds like this might be just the kind of trap I'd fall into ...

Comment: Docs say... "However, because hardware acceleration is not supported for all of the 2D drawing operations, turning it on might affect some of your custom views or drawing calls. Problems usually manifest themselves as invisible elements, exceptions, or wrongly rendered pixels. To remedy this, Android gives you the option to enable or disable hardware acceleration at multiple levels." 
Check the link for more info https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel